# Add an index in view if it is simply a simple select on one table. No joins

Tags: sql-server, view, indexed-view

I know this is DBA 101, but the question was asked and I have no answer ... well I guess what the answer is but need to confirm. I have a view (View1) that is a simple select of one table: `Select col1, col2 .... from table1 where col2=0`.
Table1 is indexed of course. When I run the Executation plan .. same results when selecting from the table or the view. So, would an index change anything on the view since it has no joins? Using SQL Server 2016.

Comment: An index helps find records, which records are to be found is determined by the `where` clause in your `select` - its irrelevant whether its a table or a view or has joins. If you want to `select * from table where Name = @Name` then an index on `Name` would help - table or view.

Comment: An index, by definition, does not "help a view" (nor a table, for that matter). It might help particular queries run against that view - but this all depends on the index and the particular queries in question.